# Querydsl Many2many join

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, subquery, querydsl

I'm rather new to QueryDSL so this may be an easy one. I have the following structure in my database:

```
 ______      ___________      _______
| user |    | user2item |    | item  |
|------|    |-----------|    |-------|
| id   |    | user_id   |    | id    |
| name |    | item_id   |    | name  |
 ------      -----------      -------
```

Now i want to get all users that have at least one item in common with a given user. So i tried:

```
JPASubQuery subQuery = new JPASubQuery().from(user, item).join(user.items, item).where(user.id.eq(myUserId));
return new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(user).where(user.items.in(subQuery.list(item))).list(user);
```

But this gives me a problem in the 'in' clause because the subquery.list() does not return a List<Item> but a ListSubQuery<Item>. Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks Timo, your suggestion works - but unfortunately if you have more than one subqueries of this kind the resulting statement is much slower than:

```
User myUser = repository.findOne(myUserId);

return new JPAQuery(entityManager)
           .from(user)
           .join(user.items, item)
           .where(item.in(myUser.getItems()))
           .list(user);
```

Comment: Ok, I will see what could be the reason for the performance difference. You might get duplicate results because of the join.

Comment: Hi Timo, my example was a little bit simplified to illustrate my problem, so if i do the query just like i wrote here (with only one subquery and no other conditions) the speed is ok. But in my real-world application i used two subqueries of this kind and this seems to break the performance neck.

Comment: Ok. Did you try item.in(myUser.getItems())? That's at least more compact.

Comment: I just tried and it looks good - many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead

```
JPASubQuery subQuery = new JPASubQuery()
  .from(user, item).join(user.items, item)
  .where(user.id.eq(myUserId));
return new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(user)
  .where(user.items.any().in(subQuery.list(item))).list(user);
```

Comment: Timo, thanks for this answer. I had similar problem, having user-many2many-roles relationship. I queried all users in a role like this: `new JPAQuery(em).from(user).where(user.roles.any().name.eq("ADMIN")).list(user)` This worked, but it did one join too many: `SELECT ...
FROM user t0 WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM userRoles t3, roles t2, roles t1
 WHERE (((t1.id = t2.id) AND (t1.name = 'ADMIN')) AND ((t3.user_id = t0.id) AND (t2.id = t3.role_id))));` It seems to work without join to t1 and its condition - is it really unnecessary to have it there? Any in my case seems more readable.

Comment: Uinsg subquery and 'in' clause is not so efficient